Having problems with diffraction pattern generation in mathematica
I am unsure about the results, but is it possible to generate diffraction pattern like following in the second picture. The following equation is like this added in the first picture for different wavelengths. The graph are plotted in the picture as Intensity vs Radial position in the far field (r).
Equation that need to be solved

Simulated pattern

Intensity vs Radial position

Tried the Nintegrate but unable solve and map the following results.

Can you add your code?

You'll probably find a more appropriate audience at mathematica.stackexchange.com.
